# jquery file upload alert on maxNumberOfFiles

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-file-upload

I am using jQuery File Upload plugin (http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/) for image upload for my website.

My Code:

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    url: 'server/index.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    dropZone: $('#dropzone'),
    disableImageResize: false,
    imageMaxWidth: 800,
    imageMaxHeight: 800,
    acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i,
    maxNumberOfFiles:3,
    singleFileUploads: false,
});
```

When user try to upload more than 3 files, the script does prevent files from being uploaded. But it doesn't do anything or show anything to tell user that their files is over limit.

So, how can I have the plugin to display an alert box when user try to upload files more than maximum number allowed?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I guess there is no direct way. You have to program it manually yourself.

```
('#fileupload').fileupload({
 ....
}).on('fileuploadadd', function (e, data) {
//program your logic here
filenum = data.files.length;
...
});
```

Comment: it is always 1
filenum = data.files.length;

Answer (score 1):

Use `limitMultiFileUploads` instead of `maxNumberOfFiles` like,

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    url: 'server/index.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    dropZone: $('#dropzone'),
    disableImageResize: false,
    imageMaxWidth: 800,
    imageMaxHeight: 800,
    acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i,
    limitMultiFileUploads:3, // use limitMultiFileUploads here
    singleFileUploads: false,
});
```

You can use `limitMultiFileUploadSize` for total file size limit.

Read **[jQuery-File-Upload-options](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options)**

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But after using limitMultiFileUploads, it seems upload files seperately and bypass singleFileUploads setting.

Comment: Yeah, lots of people like to downvote without any reason. I think stackoverflow should disable this feature, it is truly meaningless.

Comment: Did you try `singleFileUploads: true,` option

Comment: For my case here, I need to set `singleFileUploads: false`. Anyway, how can I display alert box when user upload over the limit?